Were animal sin offerings common in Torah times?
I guess my question is concerns having to do with the cost of the animals.  Of course I’m assuming there were substitutes such as far less expensive offerings.

Samuel 1:2:12-17 sounds like it was common enough

Thank you sir, appreciate it

The sources indicate that animals were not that expensive.

@N.T. what sources?
