Sacrific volume
From Lev. 1:2, "when any one of you brings an offering to the Lord" - the sheer volume of sacrifice indicated here seems a staggering amount of work, killing, preparing, burning.  How did the priests keep up?  Even the act of leading a bull to the alter would be no small task.  Grateful for any insight.

Welcome to MiYodeya David and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see here for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

similar https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/144174/759

The Mishna in Yoma (25a) indicates that a sacrifice would normally be done by a team of Kohanim, such that any individual load was bearable.

The second daily lottery: Who would slaughter, who would sprinkle the
blood on the Outer Altar, who would clear away the ashes from the
Inner Altar, who would clear away the ashes from the Menorah, who
would carry the limbs partway up the Ramp of the Outer Altar--the head
and one back leg, the two forelegs, the rump and the tail, the breast
and the throat, each of the two flanks, the innards--who would perform
the service of the accompanying Flour Offering, of the pancakes, and
of the wine.  Thirteen kohanim altogether would win this lottery.  Ben
Azzai quoted the view of Rabbi Yehoshua in the presence of Rabbi Akiva
that the sacrifice was brought up in the order in which it walked
(that is, first the front parts of the animal, and then the back parts
of the animal).

Of course, it is obvious that this could only be done once a sufficient population of kohanim existed.  In the early days, when it was only Aaron and his sons, they must have been very busy indeed!

In the following video Simcha Jacobovici explains that based on the size of the bones they find in archeological digs in Israel, the biblical cows were smaller 2000 years ago. There was not so much problem in doing the task as a result. Additional proof one can find in the Siege of Lachish relief found in Ninveh (capital of Assyrian Empire), which documents the battle of Assyrian and Israeli armies, and the aftermath exile of the Israelites by Sanherib. Here is the part showing the Israeli prisoner leading his cattle:

As one can easily see, the grown cattle is as tall as children and significantly shorter than adult men. Therefore, a grown Kohein could lead, tie, and slaughter tied oxen on his own. Carrying of the body parts is described in mishnayot Yoma and Tamid was not as strenuous as it may seem.
This also answers the question why animals, such as cows, sheep, goats were about a factor of 0.1 cheaper compared to prices now.
